# Can I use more than one TMP_Text or TextMeshPro in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textmeshpro

I'm trying to display a 2 results, but it will only display on the first TextMeshPro

Can I add multiple TMP_Text?

Also, how use call it if I tag the TMP_Text?

Comment: I have no idea what is being asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create additional empty game object and assign a TMP_Text to it. To call it from code just add aditional field with TMP_Text type

Comment: I did add a game object and add TMP_Text to it and seprate script but still it only writes to the first TMP_text on the first gameObject

Comment: I found out the issue after noticing not geting the results since I had 2 scripts for the OnTriggerStay collider, once I had put evrything in one OnTriggerStay collider script it showed results for both objects on each TMP_Text I assigned to each object on 2 diffrent scripts